# How to prove the multiplicative cancellation of the orders on natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove the statement

$$m < n \iff mp < np$$

for all $m, n, p \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p$ non-zero.

The implication seems easy enough, with

$$m < n \implies n = m + c \implies np = (m + c)p = mp + cp \implies mp < np$$

for $c, cp$ non-zero (which is easy to prove) being a fairly simple deduction. However, whenever I try to tackle the converse I get stuck almost immediately.

All my attempts are halted after $mp < np \implies np = mp + c$ with no ideas where to go. Is there a simple proof that I'm just missing?

Comment: Divide both sides by $p$?

Comment: @Raffaele I assume OP wants a proof in PA, i.e. not leaving $\Bbb N$.

Comment: You can probably do it by contradiction. Assuming $m\ge n$ and deducing $mp\ge np$ is almost the same as the first direction and some additional case for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without requiring division or subtraction (both may be problematic when working explicitly only in $\Bbb N$:

Assume $mp<np$. Exactly one of $m<n$, $m=n$, $m>n$ is true. Of course, $m=n$ would lead to $mp=np$, and you already showed, $m>n$ would lead to $mp>np$. Hence only $m<n$ remains.

Answer (score 0):

Since, $n>m$ or $n-m>0$, we obtain:

$$np-mp=(n-m)p>0,$$
which gives $np>mp.$

Comment: This addresses the $\Rightarrow$ direction the OP found easy enough, not the $\Leftarrow$ direction they got stuck on.

Comment: @kimchi lover If $np-mp>0$ so $(n-m)p>0$ and since $p>0$, we obtain $n-m>0$ or $n>m.$